vscode flutter xCode 16 Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'Foundation' is needed but has not been provided, and implicit use of module files is disabled
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/gaoang/workPlace/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (6 days ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/gaoang/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16A242d
    • CocoaPods version 1.14.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.96.0

flutter+xcode15   vscode  run is ok!
then upgrade to xcode16    vscode  run  flutter  code have this 。
>     > Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Parse
>     > Issue (Xcode): Module 'Foundation' is needed but has not been
>     > provided, and implicit use of module files is disabled

try upgrade vscode to the last versin。can't   work
how fix this issue，

Hello, i guess your problem is already answered in here Xcode 9 "could not build module ‘Foundation’"

Since there's no accepted answer yet in the previous similiar question i'll break down the option:
Option 1 - Enable Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules

Open your project in Xcode (your iOS folder)
Select runner on your left menu
Then go to Build Settings section
Search (in filter) allow non-modular includes in framework (or you can find manually in Apple Clang - Language - Modules section)
Set the variable to yes

Option 2 - Reinstall Xcode

This answer based on Xcode 15.4.


have try  this two menths, but  that no work for me
